# Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple undirected graph with $n = |V | \ge 1$ vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple undirected graph with $n = |V | \ge 1$ vertices. A subset $U \subseteq V$ of the vertices is called a vc-set if for every edge $\{i, j\} \in E$ either $i \in U$ or $j \in U$ (or both). Let $U^∗$ be a vc-set for $G$ that has the smallest size possible (meaning there does not exist any other vc-set $U'$ such that ($|U'| < |U^∗|$). A subset $W \subseteq V$ of the vertices of $G$ is called an in-set if for all $i, j \in W, \{i, j\} \not\in E$. Let $W^∗$ be a largest possible in-set in $G$ (meaning there is no other in-set, $W′$, such that $|W^∗| < |W^{'}|$). Prove that $|W^∗| = n − |U^∗|$. I tried to use the basics of graph theory but was of no use as I got stuck and back to the starting point. If you could help me I would be really grateful thanks a ton!

Comment: Rather than "vc-set" and "in-set", most mathematicians use "vertex cover" and "independent set" (or, occasionally, "stable set").

Comment: That’s fine but how to prove it

Comment: You have the definitions of each kind of set. The answer below tells you what to do. Suppose that a set $U$ satisfies the definition of a vertex cover (or vc-set). Prove that its complement satisfies the definition of an independent set.

Comment: Could you please show me the starting steps to prove it

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to show that for any vc-set $U$, its complement is an in-set.

Comment: Yeah but how should I show that?

Comment: @Daniel Check the definitions.